# Adjusting overline padding in TextBlock <span>

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am using `<Span TextDecorations="Overline" BaselineAlignment="Bottom">` inside a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="276">
    Hello world. This is some text. This is an 
    <Span TextDecorations="Overline" BaselineAlignment="Bottom">
        OVERLINE
    </Span>
</TextBlock>
```

Producing:

[image: Screen Shot]

Is there any way to decrease the space between the top of a character and the overline? For example, I would prefer:

[image]

Very subtle shift down, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to create your own **TextDecoration** with yours specific needs.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="276">
    Hello world. This is some text. This is an
    <Span BaselineAlignment="Bottom">
        <Span.TextDecorations>
            <TextDecoration Location="OverLine" PenOffset="1" PenOffsetUnit="Pixel" />
        </Span.TextDecorations>
        OVERLINE
    </Span>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks stukselbax and sorry for delay in responding: came down with a bug. I changed PenOffset to 2 and now have the desired look. Awesome!